# How can I push docker compose based images for Gitlab Registry Using CI/CD

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, gitlab, cicd

I've linked Postgres DB & API images using docker-compose, its working in local, I've to push both image for gitlab registry Using CI/CD.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQhLG.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gitlab docs cover how to [build and push Docker images during CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#container-registry-examples-with-gitlab-cicd) quite well.

It is important to note/use the `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` variable. If the image name you try to push is different from `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE`, the push will fail. If you want to have multiple images, you either need to label them in the tag (`$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:db-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG`) or create a separate repo and manage the images there.